# Change function for "Power Button"

Tags: 18.04, power-management, acpi, button

I want to change functionality for Power Button in Ubuntu 18.04.

I need following: when someone press Power Button, logged in user should be logged out, and specific user automatically logged in (without entering user password).

Is there a way to do this?